# Google Sandbox Checkout Credit Card Failure Test cases

Tags: payment-gateway, sandbox, google-checkout

I have integrated Google Checkout to my portal & testing against sandbox using Server 2 Server Checkout using version 2.0. All successful credit card test cases are passing, however credit card test failure cases documented in https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Credit_Card_Test_Cases#test_case_failed_authorization are failing.

For Eg: if use AVS No Match MasterCard: 5106447623213738 as said in the URL, i expect Google Servers to reply with PAYMENT_DECLINED or authorization failed, but the callback is success & card is shown as charged. I tried other credit cards too in box all those cards are shown charged.

Note: This testing in done in google checkout sandbox (http://sandbox.google.com/checkout) & haven't gone live yet, but would like to test credit card failure test cases. I did lot of searching around to test failure cases but could not get around. Can someone tell me how to do ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of `AVS NO MATCH` is doing exactly what the test is supposed to do.

[image: AVS No match]

It is showing you that Google will allow certain transactions and **let the merchant make the decison** (assume risk) for the transaction. You will also notice that this transaction is **not** covered by Google's Payment Guarantee (which is why merchant assumes risk).

A transaction that is covered by Google Payment Guarantee will show:

[image: covered by payment guarantee]

The [link you provided for `AUTH DECLINE` (Failed auth)](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Credit_Card_Test_Cases#test_case_failed_authorization) is what you are looking for - re: Google will not let the transaction go through (e.g. VISA 4209, AUTH+DECLINE):

[image]

Comment: Hello Ed. Thank you very much. I was a bit confused. I have another question. I tried CVV error case & in my merchant panel noticed that AVS is FULL & CVV is error, but google shows the order as Shipped & charged. is it possible that google can report CVV as error but the transaction may still be chargeable ?  How is it possible that CVV was error but the order was still charged ? i use digital delivery. Many thanks

Comment: @Anita Don't assume that Google will reject based on it - I think that's the key. Google will run their own risk engine and either reject, accept or pass the decision to you (merchant). So if your own risk analysis dictates that you should reject based on CVV error, then by all means you can do so (it's just that Google didn't decide for you).